# Add or Remove my Date of Birth on Linkedin

Tags: linkedin

Does anyone know how to add or remove your own birthday on Linkedin.  When you google this all the answers are about removing birthday notifications, or are relevant to the old linkedin and no longer work.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2):

In your profile page select "Contact info" (right under you name and profile picture and next to your connections).
Click on the pen icon the upper right corner to edit this section. In the birthday section instead of your current date choose generic Day and Month at the top of the list.
Click Save.
This should erase your birthday from your profile.